# CoreLocation in Swift Playground

Tags: swift, xcode, location, core-location, swift-playground

I am trying to retrieve the current location of a user but in Swift Playgrounds. I have this code already but for some reason it never executes the print statements. Could anyone help?

```
import UIKit  
import CoreLocation  
import PlaygroundSupport  

var str = "Hello, playground"  
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()  
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true  

class GeoCoordinateDelegate: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {  

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {  
        let location = locations[0]  
        print("Most Recent Location: " + location.description)  
        print(location.coordinate.latitude)  
        print(location.coordinate.longitude)  
    }  

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {  
        print("Error while updating " + error.localizedDescription)  
    }  

}  
let geoCoordinateDelegate = GeoCoordinateDelegate()  
locationManager.delegate = geoCoordinateDelegate  
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest  
locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
```

Answer (score 1):

When writing CoreLocation code, it is good practice to check `CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled()` before trying to perform any location related actions.

In Swift Playgrounds (1.2 from 2017-03-21), that method returns `false` as CoreLocation is not available for playgrounds (yet?). I suggest to file a bug report at https://bugreport.apple.com/